# How to trim text before saving in system.xml

Tags: magento2, xml, system.xml

In my custom module in system.xml in Admin I have field:

```
 <field id="user_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
       <label>User ID Key</label>
       <comment>Set User Key</comment>
 </field>
```

I save that field to database.

I need to trim it before it is saved.

Is there any mechanism to trim it before it is saved?

Something like:

```
<field id="user_key" trim="1" (...)
```